# ¿Como manejar la cookie de mi jwt?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, jwt

Tengo una api con jwt que me entrega un `token` de autorizacion para poder navegar en la aplicacion que consume a la api, este `token` tiene una fecha de caducidad y es aca mi pregunta. ¿Como puedo manejar esto desde mi aplicacion cliente, para ir validando en que momento el `token expiro?` y poder hacer el logout del usuario.

Answer (score 0):

La fecha de expiación es un [campo del token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token#Standard_fields). Una vez que hayas decodificado el token en el cliente podrás acceder a este campo y comparar con la fecha actual para determinar si esta expirado o no.

Comment: ¿Y como puedo decodificar el token en mi app cliente?